# Как исправить ошибку в уже установленной системе "федора-13"?

Tags: php, fedora, linux

При попытке обновления сообщение

> РНР-3.2.1 содержит ошибку, рекомендуется заменить либо на РНР-3.2.0 , либо на РНР-3.2.2.

Можно ли это сделать в графическом режиме? Если нет, то какие действия надо сделать в командной строке?

Answer (score 1):

поверьте, скорее всего будет быстрее и проще переустановить новую версию php, чем искать ошибку в установленной. установить новую версию совсем не сложно. Думаю, в вашем случае сначала надо удалить сам php и все его следы на сервере, а потом установить заново более новую версию. Удалить можно посмотрев, где размещаются файлы модулей php (это смотриться в конфиг файле веб-сервера), затем удаляются файлы модулей и иже с ними (ну обычно они храняться в отдельной директории, так что всю директорию, например /etc/apache/php52 можно удалить), затем я бы закомеентировал строки, указывающие на модули php в конфиге сервера. Потом бы собрал новый пхп (предпочитаю из сырцов) и снова бы прописал путь к его модулям в конфиге апача.